# How do I modify all occurrences of a property (including nested) in an object before sending a JSON response?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an object created by parsing some JSON. The JSON data looks like this:

```
  {
    "id": "fan",
    "name": "My super awesome fan",
    "image": "Icon.png",
    "details": {
      "parts": [
        {
          "name": "base",
          "image": "base.png"
        },
        {
          "name": "blades",
          "image": "blade.png"
        }
      ],
      "sale": {
        "value": "prime",
        "image": "PrimeDay.png"
      }
    }
  }
```

The values in the image property point to files located under the directory "public" which is served using express.static. For example, the blade.png file is located at:

```
public
  --products
    --fan (this is the same as the id property)
      --blade.png
```

Now, when a query is made to fetch the details of this object, I want to modify the image property of the object sent in the response so that the JSON response looks like:

```
  {
    "id": "fan",
    "name": "My super awesome fan",
    "image": "http://localhost:3000/products/fan/icon.png",
    "details": {
      "parts": [
        {
          "name": "base",
          "image": "http://localhost:3000/products/fan/base.png"
        },
        {
          "name": "blades",
          "image": "http://localhost:3000/products/fan/blade.png"
        }
      ],
      "sale": {
        "value": "prime",
        "image": "http://localhost:3000/products/fan/PrimeDay.png"
      }
    }
  }
```

I went down the path of using an express middleware to create a url to point to the path of the  using

```
const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
```

How do I use this `url` value to modify the response object?
I don't want to hardcode the full localhost path to the images in the JSON, since the path may change when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, partly using Charly's solution. The only reason I could not use it fully was because the `fan` part of the URL is also dynamic and is dependent on the `id` property in the JSON data.

Here's my approach:

```
setImagePaths = (data) => {
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/products/'
    const baseId = data.id;

    const patchImagePaths = (obj) => {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                return patchImagePaths(obj[key]);
            }
            if (key === 'image') {
                obj[key] = baseUrl + baseId + '/' + obj[key];
            }
        });
    }

    patchImagePaths(data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could modify your response object with a recursive function to update the image properties:

```
var myObject =   {
  "id": "fan",
  "name": "My super awesome fan",
  "image": "Icon.png",
  "details": {
    "parts": [
      {
        "name": "base",
        "image": "base.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "blades",
        "image": "blade.png"
      }
    ],
    "sale": {
      "value": "prime",
      "image": "PrimeDay.png"
    }
  }
}
;

const url = "http://localhost:3000/products/fan/";
//You can use here your url function with whatever output it has.

function resetImages (obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
      if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
          let arr = obj[key];
          arr.map((i)=>{
            return i.image = url+i.image;
          });
          return arr;
      }
      if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
          return resetImages(obj[key]);
      }
      if(key==="image") {
        obj[key]=url+obj[key];
      }
  });
}




resetImages(myObject);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));

**Output:**

{"id":"fan","name":"My super awesome fan","image":"http://localhost:3000/products/fan/Icon.png","details":{"parts":[{"name":"base","image":"http://localhost:3000/products/fan/base.png"},{"name":"blades","image":"http://localhost:3000/products/fan/blade.png"}],"sale":{"value":"prime","image":"http://localhost:3000/products/fan/PrimeDay.png"}}}
```